# Correctly pass view errors to template with Django

Tags: django

How can I pass errors to display them in templates, using a clean and common way ?

I'd like to show errors through an overlay box message.

- Transmit an Error object for each return ?
- Push it in session, and check it in template ?
- Check from template using an Ajax method ?
- Use a common error template page ? (not very user friendly..)

I'm confused when using HttpResponseRedirect ; unless using session variables, it's not possible to pass errors.

Comment: Have you looked at messages framework, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The usual way is to use [Django's message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/), like Rohan said.

Anywhere in your view, you can use this code to pass errors to the templates :

```
from django.contrib import messages


def my_view(request):
    …
    messages.error(request, 'Oops, something bad happened')
    return redirect…
```

You can add the following code in your `base.html` template to display those messages (here using bootstrap classes):

```
{% if messages %}
<div class="span12">
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
        {{ message|safe }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: seems perfect :p i'll test it